# Triple UISwitch

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiswitch

I want to create a custom UISwtich with three positions. Is it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be using `UISegmentedControl`if you want a standard UI-Element or configure a `UISlider` with a range of 2:

```
slider.minimumValue = 0; 
slider.maximumValue = 2;
slider.continuous = NO;
```

And then set the `minimumValueImage`, `maximumTrackImage` and `thumbImage` to use appropriate images.

Comment: Using a UISegmentedControl is a great idea! The problem with UISlider is you have to touch on the ball to change the value and the experience is not so nice. I think I will use UISegmentedControl, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Not using the built-in UISwitch. You'll need to roll your own.

Answer (score 4):

Why not use a UISegmentedControl?

Answer (score 0):

Using UISlider is a good approach. But you would additionally want to adjust the mechanics of your UISlider to be more UISwitch-like. I.e., when you change its position incompletely then it should bounce back to the home position.

Here's what I ended up doing (using a part of FelixLam's answer):

```
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(screenRect.size.width*0.5-width/2, screenRect.size.height*0.95-height, width, height)];

slider.minimumValue = 0; 
slider.maximumValue = 2;
slider.continuous = NO;
slider.value = 1;

[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Along with...

```
- (void)sliderAction:(UISlider *)slider {
    float origValue = slider.value;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    if (slider.value<1.9 && slider.value>0.1) slider.value=1;
    else if (slider.value>1.9) slider.value=2;
    else slider.value=0;
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2*fabs(slider.value-origValue)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```