# Selection among three values

Tags: iphone, uiswitch

What is the best way in iphone to select a value among three? Is it possible to make UISwitch to has three values?

Comment: Check this question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147462/triple-uiswitch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147462/triple-uiswitch)

Answer (score 0):

In this condition I suggest you to use `UISegmentedControl` that will we simple and **[here](http://mobileappmastery.com/2010/03/here-is-how-you-use-uisegmentedcontrol/)** is how you use `UISegmentedControl`

Good Luck!